# mac cornerstone could not contact repository to read the latest log entries

Tags: macos, svn, cornerstone

Error Message: Cound not contact repository to read the latest log entries. The log displayed meb be incomplete. 
why? thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem and emailed Zennaware's Cornerstone support. They sent me these instructions that seem to have fixed the problem for me:

1. Quit Cornerstone
2. Open Terminal
3. Copy paste the following line into Terminal:

defaults delete com.zennaware.Cornerstone HistoryCacheUsage

4. Press return
5. Open Finder
6. Select Go->Go To Folder…
7. Enter:

~/Library/Caches/Cornerstone

and click “Go”
8. Move the selected directory (“Cornerstone”) to the Trash.
9. Restart Cornerstone

The next time Cornerstone prompts you to cache the repository log, choose “Never”.

Comment: Thanks! _defaults delete com.zennaware.Cornerstone HistoryCacheUsage_ was a huge help.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, it says "Domain (com.zennaware.Cornerstone) not found.
Defaults have not been changed."

Comment: Same issue as Biclops. Did the name get changed when they were acquired by Assembla? I tried using com.assembla.Cornerstone, but that didn't work either. I'm not seeing anything that looks relevant in ~/Library/Caches either.